# C code in Swift

Tags: ios, c, xcode, matlab, swift2

I struggle myself with connecting C code exported from Matlab and Swift code. Project demands that I import image from Swift to algorithm written in Matlab. This is done when application takes picture, and store it in variable and save it in library (not requirement).
From variable, image should be transformed to array of uint8_T, because function from C code (exported matlab code) is expecting such format.
I have imported code inside my project and I have connected bridge-header [connection made here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC1Py.png)

After that I set mmmBase_initialize(); and mmmBase_terminate(); to AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     mmmBase_initialize();
    return true
}
```

and

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    mmmBase_terminate();
}
```

After all of this, I have created simple @IBAction for taking photo and all of his helper methods, which work flawlessly and image is displayed and stored without problems. When I have been completely certain that this works I added mmmBase function from C to imagePickerController for algorithm to start working on image as soon as is taken.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);

    if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as String {
       let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
           as! UIImage

        mmmBase(INPUT MATRIX, OUTPUT MATRIX)

        if (newMedia == true) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,
               "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
       } else if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as String {
           // Code to support video here
      }
```

mmmBase() function in mmmBase.h look like this:

```
extern void mmmBase(const emxArray_uint8_T *imgIn, emxArray_uint8_T *imgOut);
```

Next step should be to transform Image to uint8_T array and to create INPUT MATRIX with code that is in mmmBase_emxAPI.h

```
extern emxArray_uint8_T *emxCreateND_uint8_T(int numDimensions, int *size);
extern emxArray_uint8_T *emxCreateWrapperND_uint8_T(unsigned char *data, int numDimensions, int *size);
extern emxArray_uint8_T *emxCreateWrapper_uint8_T(unsigned char *data, int rows, int cols);
extern emxArray_uint8_T *emxCreate_uint8_T(int rows, int cols);
extern void emxDestroyArray_uint8_T(emxArray_uint8_T *emxArray);
extern void emxInitArray_uint8_T(emxArray_uint8_T **pEmxArray, int numDimensions);
```

These wrapper should be used as on following link:
http://newtips.co/st/questions/24229038/how-to-use-c-library-created-by-matlab-coder-codegen-in-c-program-with-emxarray.html
But I'm out of idea how should one use them in swift, I would be immensely grateful if somebody gave me piece of information how to use them in Swift together with Pointers that as I found must me also used.

In my last effort I manage to write this code, and it seems to sends array to Algorithm and crashes randomly but I still cannot get outPut parameter which is second parameter in mmmBase() function. I wrote this last code in despair.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);

    if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as String {
       let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
           as! UIImage

        let unwrappedImage = image
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(unwrappedImage, 1.0)

        var bytes = data!.bytes
        let len = data!.length;
        let dataint = UnsafeMutablePointer<uint8_T>(bytes)
        let br = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>(bitPattern: len)
        let InputMatix = emxCreateWrapperND_uint8_T(dataint,1,br)

        let dataout = UnsafeMutablePointer<uint8_T>()
        var dataoutWR = emxCreateWrapperND_uint8_T(dataout,1,br)

        mmmBase(InputMatix, dataoutWR)

        endImage = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: len)\\ Global variable endImage


        if (newMedia == true) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,
               "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
       } else if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as String {
           // Code to support video here
      }



        let mainstoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: ViewControllerLast = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testController") as! ViewControllerLast

        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        var image1: UIImage = UIImage(data: endImage)!
        vc.image = image1 as UIImage

   }
```

At the end I would like to mention that Im not proficient with Swift. And in short terms picture should be send to Matlab algorithm there it should be processed and send back to Swift to be displayed in "testController".

Comment: I found solution to this problem, it is quite complex... Posting in few days.